# How fix error: "Error: start must be <= end"

Tags: node.js

I have a server that is serving large files and it's supporting range requests.

But when it is about to complete, nodejs is throwing this error:

```
fs.js:1488
      throw new Error('start must be <= end');
            ^
Error: start must be <= end
    at new ReadStream (fs.js:1488:13)
    at Object.fs.createReadStream (fs.js:1449:10)
    at inicioStream (/home/harold/fileserver/app.js:639:17)
    at fn (/home/harold/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:641:34)
    at Object._onImmediate (/home/harold/node_modules/async/lib/async.js:557:34)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:345:15)
```

I'd like to know what it is and how to fix it.

Here it is the part of the code that is generating this error:

```
var path = __dirname + '/backup/'+location;
var rs = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: download.range.start, end: download.range.end});
```

Thank you!

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you mean by "supporting range requests"?

It looks like an invalid range (a range where the start was greater than the end) was passed, but without more info I couldn't say where it was coming from.

Comment: The user can make partial requests. With the "Range" http header.

Answer (score 0):

Since users can make partial requests for these large files via the `Range` HTTP header, this error can get thrown anytime the range happens to be invalid. In this case, the range requested is invalid because the value of `download.range.start` is greater than `download.range.end`, when it must always be the other way around.

Because there's always a possibility this error can arise, you'll need to catch it in your code:

```
var rs = fs.createReadStream(path, {start: download.range.start, end: download.range.end});
rs.on('error', function(err) {
  // code to handle error - maybe return a response saying the range is invalid?
});
```

Comment: I haven't thought about this possibility and will fix my code but this is not the case now. The download hasn't been completed and is throwing this error when the file is 99,99% downloaded. Is very at the end of the download. And I am not trying to break my code, not yet.

Comment: Hmm I'm not sure what's going on then. Would you mind updating your code above with the value of `download`?

Comment: Actually looking at the docs for [fs.createReadStream](http://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_createreadstream_path_options), I'm wondering if you need to pass an `encoding` property in the `options` object too.

Comment: There is nothing fancy on my code... Is just parsing the range header and setting to download.range.start and download.range.end. I think that the Download Manager is sending some different request at the end. I will dig into it a little more.